# Adding Overtime Pay

Tags: c++

the program works, but i'm not sure how to get the grosspay to add the overtime pay once the if condition is set, I was told to set overtime pay to zero on the declaration. Is there a way to change the overtime pay accordingly once the if condition is met? for example
overtimepay= 50
so the formula for gross pay will now be hw*hp+ 50

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    float ftax, stax, SDI, SS, hw, hp, pay, netpay, gp, OvertimePay = 0;

    cout << "please enter the hoursWorked: ";
    cin >> hw;

    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "please enter the hourlyPay: ";
    cin >> hp;

    gp = hw * hp + (OvertimePay);
    ftax = gp*.10;
    stax = gp*.08;
    SDI = gp*.01;
    SS = gp*.06;
    netpay = gp - (ftax + stax + SDI + SS);

    cout << " grosspay = " << gp << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << " federal taxes = " << ftax << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << " state taxes = " << stax << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << " SDI = " << SDI << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Social Securities = " << SS << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << " netpay = " << netpay << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    if(hw > 40)

        cout << "OvertimePay = " << (hw - 40) * hp * 0.5 << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I suggest you step away from the code for a minute and work out an example with pencil and paper.

Comment: Unrelated: in my wildest dreams my federal tax liability is 10%. That's 24% *short*. And FICA is [7.65%](http://www.ssa.gov/pressoffice/factsheets/colafacts2014.html) (x2 but your boss gets to pay the other half). Your instructor needs to update their material =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it. You weren't ever actually setting the OvertimePay variable to equal anything other than 0. You should move the if condition up in the program logic and then set the variable accordingly before calculating gross pay (gp).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
float ftax, stax, SDI, SS, hw, hp, pay, netpay, gp, OvertimePay = 0;

cout << "please enter the hoursWorked: ";
cin >> hw;

cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << "please enter the hourlyPay: ";
cin >> hp;

if(hw > 40) {
   OvertimePay = (hw - 40) * hp * .5;
} else {
  OvertimePay = 0;
}


gp = (hw * hp) + OvertimePay;
ftax = gp*.10;
stax = gp*.08;
SDI = gp*.01;
SS = gp*.06;
netpay = gp - (ftax + stax + SDI + SS);

cout << " grosspay = " << gp << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << " federal taxes = " << ftax << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << " state taxes = " << stax << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << " SDI = " << SDI << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << " Social Securities = " << SS << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << " netpay = " << netpay << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;



}
```

Comment: The `else` is redundant, as the `OvertimePay` variable is initialized in the declaration, so `} else { OvertimePay = 0; }` can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the overtime pay first, before outputting the gross pay:

```
if(hw > 40)
    OvertimePay = (hw - 40) * hp * 0.5;

gp = hw * hp + OvertimePay;
```

Comment: I have the overtime pay already but i want it to replace the formula above for gross pay so it spits out the gross pay numbers including overtime then does all the taxes, so far my program just gives me the gross pay without overtime